# Auto populating a table as user types

Tags: javascript, jquery

To add auto populate a table as a user types entries in a text box i've been reading abouto jQuery autocomplete :

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Can this be tailored to auto-complete a table with multiple rows ?

Perhaps there is a plugin which already does this ? I'm just looking for direction on where to begin this task. All suggestions very welcome.

More detail :

As the user types in a textbox a html table is populated with suggestions based on what is typed. These suggestions are data values retrieved from a datastore. Something similar to 'google suggest' but instead of suggesting options in a text box, options are displayed in a html table. The reason I'm using a table is that the suggestions contain multiple columns of data.

Comment: Describe in detail what it is that you're trying to do..?

Comment: @David Thomas please see question edit

Answer (score 0):

You can override "renderItem" method in jQuery autocomplete to achieve that. See the example for details: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data